# Why is Eclipse stepping into when I hit step over?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I am using debug mode in Eclipse Oxygen to, as you might guess, debug my code.

I am writing a backtracking algorithm (a recursive function - it calls itself).

In the Backtrack function there is a for loop, and at the end of the for loop, if certain conditions are met, this code is run: `Backtrack(csp, index + 1, CopyCSP(currentSolution));`.

I'm debugging my code, and I want to go to the next iteration of the for loop, so when I get to this line, I hit "step over." But it steps into, and walks me through the next Backtrack function.

I know for a fact that it is actually the next function, because as you can see, the `index` variable goes up by one, which happened.

Why is this happening? How can I avoid this and actually step over? If step over doesn't do what I want here, what should I use?

Here's my code for the full function:

```
private void Backtrack(CSP csp, int index, CSP currentSolution) {
//BREAKPOINT IS HERE
    if(index == csp.numVars) {
        currentSolution.PrintSolution();
        csp.PrintSolution(currentSolution);
        solved = true;
        return;
    }
    for(int test = 0; test < csp.MaxDomainSize(); test++) {
        if(solved) {
            return;
        }
        if(test < currentSolution.vars[index].domain.size) {
            currentSolution.vars[index].value = currentSolution.vars[index].domain.get(test);
        }
        else {
            continue;
        }
        boolean satisfied = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < csp.constraints.size; i++) {
            if(!csp.constraints.get(i).Satisfied(currentSolution.vars, index)) {
                satisfied = false;
            }
        }
        if(satisfied) {
            System.out.println("Variable " + index + " satisfied by " + currentSolution.vars[index].value + ".");
            Backtrack(csp, index + 1, CopyCSP(currentSolution));
        }
    }
}
```

I've put a comment where the breakpoint is.

Comment: Do you have a breakpoint set on the method or in the body?

Comment: @ProgrammersBlock I do. Is that causing it? I thought it didn't stop at breakpoints unless you used "Resume." If that's causing it, that's a pretty big issue because I kind of need that breakpoint there to get to the part of the code I'm trying to debug, which is probably about 100 recursions deep already.

Comment: @RothX Could you show some code? "Step over" will not cause the debugger to skip to the next breakpoint. It will jump to the next statement.

Comment: A breakpoint in a recursive function will break execution in the recursive calll when you step over the recursive call.  Use a conditional breakpoint with `index==100` to stop at the 100th level deep.  Or use the “hit count” condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the train of thought that it's the breakpoint...

A breakpoint stops the flow of control in most situations.

Eclipse has options to disable individual breakpoints and disable all breakpoints.  Your situation might be right for conditional breakpoints:

1. Right click on the breakpoint and select breakpoint properties.  This will bring up a dialog with "hit count" and "conditional" which works most of the time and is confusing when it doesn't.
2. If you check "conditional", this will enable a text box where you can write a condition to use the variables to make a true statement.  So you could enter "index==1000" and then it would stop when you are 1000 calls deep.

I have not used "hit count" myself.

Comment: This solved my problem. Not sure why you are getting down voted.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem and found similar solution, posting here for reference.

**Problem:**

- Debug session 'Stepped Into' each line for every 'Step Over (F6)' operation

**Solution:**

1. '*Run->Remove All Breakpoints*'
2. '*Run->Restart*'

**Result:**

- 'Step Over (F6)' steps over active debug line now as expected.

Sharing for clarity and simplicity if encountered, hopefully this helps.